# How to extract only the first occurrence of the pattern matching from the string, in R?

Tags: pattern-matching, data-manipulation, data-extraction

How to extract only the first occurrence of the pattern matching from the string, in R,in case the given pattern has multiple matches in the string.

I have been using Strapply to extract the required part of the string but the problem here is this function returns all the multiple matches instead of the first match.

the code i used:

x <- c("ab_cdef_ghij_kl","abc_d_efgh_ijk_l","ab_cde_fghi_jk_l")
strapply(x, "._.",  simplify = T)

and i get the below output:

[[1]]

[1] "b_c" "f_g" "j_k"

[[2]]

[1] "c_d" "h_i" "k_l"

[[3]]

[1] "b_c" "e_f" "i_j" "k_l"

But what I ideally want is just the first matching occurrence as shown below:

[[1]]

[1] "b_c"

[[2]]

[1] "c_d"

[[3]]

[1] "b_c"